# Will allah judge me by intentions when by mistakely i tell the wrong line in dua

Tags: quran, hadith, sin

Recently  I am suffering  from  waswas . I have bad thoughts.and I am not giving up my salah .recently in dua I asked allah that I am dying to have that kind of thoughts. but I meant that I just want to kill myself for having such thoughts.. will allah punish me ?? But my intentions are what I meant .. but I said that I am dying to have it .please respond.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, as long as you didn't intend bad, you aren't punished for it.

> [It was narrated](http://sunnah.com/urn/1263620) from Abu Dharr Al-Ghifari that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
> Allah has forgiven for me my nation their mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do."

May Allah support you and grant you patience and award you for every second you suffer from this.

Hold tight to your prayer and never leave it.

Stay strong.